# Building Linux Kernel for Driver Creation

Tags: operating-systems, kernel, driver

**I am attempting to compile the kernel for the RPI using Raspbian. These are the steps I took...**

(1) Imaged the SD card from http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads

(2) Downloaded the kernel from and placed it in my `/usr/src` directory sudo wget https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/archive/rpi-3.6.y.zip

**Now I would like to run the following commands to create the new image file...**

(1) `sudo make menuconfig`

(2) `sudo make`

(3) `sudo make modules`

(4) `sudo make modules_install`

**The first problem I have is that I want to compile using the header files from my downloaded kernel and no the current system kernel. (I am compiling on the actual RPI) How do I change it so that happens.**

**My second question is are there any special configurations needed to be done during step 1 `sudo make menuconfig` so that I can write my own drivers?**

Answer (score 1):

> The first problem I have is that I want to compile using the header files from my downloaded kernel and no the current system kernel. (I am compiling on the actual RPI) How do I change it so that happens.

If you call `make` to do anything in the src directory, it will use the src directory makefile which will include the correct src directory headers.

> My second question is are there any special configurations needed to be done during step 1 sudo make menuconfig so that I can write my own drivers?

No.  I believe (I haven't tried) you should even be able to integrate your module's build with `make menuconfig` if you include a Kconfig file and probably an appropriate makefile.  However, that's not necessary to build a custom module.  Beware they are built for specific kernels, so if you build it for the 3.6.x kernel you can't load it into the 3.2.27 kernel; you'd have to build two versions.

WRT to replacing the existing system headers, you can do this (see `src/doc/Documentation/make/headers_install.txt`), but the general wisdom is not to -- the distro headers are the ones glibc, etc, was built against, and those are the ones that should be used for compiling *userspace* applications (but not modules).